How to add a none-database row to a DetailView
I have 'view.php" file that have a yii\widgets\DetailView; on it.
    DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'feed',
            'feedname',
            ...
            'filename',
        ],
    ])

I want to add another 'attribute' that loads the 'filename' information into an <audio></audio> tag.
So is it as simple as:
            [
                'attribute' => '',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    // create the Tag
                    return $audioTag;
                },
            ],

Can I have a blank attribute? Can I just delete 'attribute' => '',?
Can I add an item in the model->attributeLabels and use it as the attribute and get a "Play this" in the header section?

You can leave out the attribute option if you specify both label and value.
[
    'label' => 'Play this',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        // create the Tag
        return $audioTag;
    },
],


Thank You. Sometimes it's the little things that wrap you up. :)
Now all I have to do is load the audio file from protected directory :(
